# Torrent autodownload using RSS

Tags: rss, bittorrent

Is there a convenient software to auto-download torrents published in an RSS feed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[µTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) can do that, its RSS support is pretty good.

See [documentation](http://www.utorrent.com/documentation/rss).

Answer (score 1):

See these articles:

[How to use RSS & BitTorrent to download TV shows](http://torrentfreak.com/how-to-use-rss-bittorrent-to-download-tv-shows/)
[How To Use RSS Feeds To Download Torrents Automatically](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-use-rss-feeds-to-download-torrents-easily-and-automatically/)